# Creating a filterable list using Laravel and Eloquent queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm developing an API for an app and the results of offers need to be filterable, examples of this would be:

```
Filters
Price Min  -  Price Max
Category Ids
Min Review (1-5 stars) if 3 is sent then only 3 and above
Min Distance
Max Distance
Location (for the above 2) 


Sort By
Distance,
Price,
Review
```

I'm confused on the most efficient way to do this, I will be posting the users filter options but executing a query based on their options is the part that has me lost.

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks all :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: Why bothering with Eloquent? Why not using QueryBuilder?
From my experience, any way you will end up writing custom SQL queries (as filters get more complicated), which QueryBuilder is perfect for.

Comment: I see, I was just looking for a point in the right direction, I think @pumbo is right though.T

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start applying conditions on your queries, you'll need to take note of the following function: [`newQuery()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_newQuery). This function will allow you to start a new query builder and chain your filters/order bys onto it.

**Example Schema:**

Columns in **Product**  table:

`id | name | price | date_received`

Columns in **product_tag** table:

`id | tag_id | product_id`

Column in **tag** table:

`id | name`

**Relationship:**

- Many products have many tags

I won't be setting up the eloquent models, though note that Product model has a `tag()` function with a `hasManyThrough()` relationship

A filter class has been setup with the main purpose of applying your filters & order bys. Note: The class can be abstracted even further.

**Your Filter Class:**

```
class ProductFilter {

    /**
    * Fluent query builder
    * @var mixed $queryBuilder
    */
    private $queryBuilder;

    /**
    * Http Request
    * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
    */
    protected $request;

    /**
    * Filters collection
    * @var array $filters
    */
    private $filters = [];

    /**
    * Order Bys Collection
    * @var array $orderBys
    */
    private $orderBys = [];

    /**
    * Class constructor
    *
    * @param array $input
    */
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, &$queryBuilder)
    {
        //Initialize Query Builder
        $this->queryBuilder = $queryBuilder;
        //Get input
        $this->request = $request;

        //Register Filters
        $this->registerFilters();

        //Register Order Bys
        $this->registerOrderBys();
    }

    /**
     * Register Filters in the function below
     * Each filter is in the form of an array
     */

    private function registerFilters()
    {
        $this->filters['product_name'] = ['name'=>'Name',
                                                'value' => $this->request->get('filter_product_name'),
                                                'enabled' => $this->request->has('filter_product_name'),
                                                'function' => 'filterProductName'
                                            ];

        $this->filters['tag'] = ['name'=>'End Date',
                                            'value' => $this->request->get('filter_tag'),
                                            'enabled' => $this->request->has('filter_tag'),
                                            'function' => 'filterTag'
                                        ];
    }

    /**
    * Check if any filters are active
    * Useful to show/hide filter bar
    * 
    * @return bool
    */
    public function isFiltersActive()
    {
        return (boolean)count(
            array_filter($this->filters,function($v){
                return $v['enabled'] === true;
            })
        );        
    }

    /**
    * Register Order Bys in the function below
    * Each order by is in the form of an array
    *
    */
    private function registerOrderBys()
    {
        $this->orderBys['name'] = [
                                    'name' => 'Order By Name',
                                    'value' => $this->request->get('order_by_product_name','ASC'),
                                    'enabled' => $this->request->has('order_by_product_name'),
                                    'function' => 'orderByProductName'
                                  ];
    }

    /**
    * Check if any order bys are active
    * Useful to show/hide order by bar
    * 
    * @return bool
    */
    public function isOrderBysActive()
    {
        return (boolean)count(
            array_filter($this->orderBys,function($v){
                return $v['enabled'] === true;
            })
        );        
    }    

    /**
     * Apply Filters
     * Loop through each filter, check if they are enabled. If they are, apply filter to query builder
     */

    public function applyFilters()
    {
        foreach($this->filters as $filter_name => $filter_array)
        {
            if($filter_array['enabled'] &&
                array_key_exists('function',$filter_array) &&
                method_exists($this,$filter_array['function']))
            {
                $this->{$filter_array['function']}($filter_array);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Apply Order Bys
     * Loop through each order by, check if they are enabled. If they are, apply order by to query builder
     */

    public function applyFilters()
    {
        foreach($this->orderBys as $order_by_name => $order_by_array)
        {
            if($order_by_array['enabled'] &&
                array_key_exists('function',$order_by_array) &&
                method_exists($this,$order_by_array['function']))
            {
                $this->{$order_by_array['function']}($order_by_array);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }    

    /*
     * Filter Functions: START
     */

    /**
    * Filter by Product Name
    *
    * @param array $filterArray
    */
    private function filterProductName($filterArray)
    {
        $this->queryBuilder
            ->where('name','=',$filterArray['value']);
    }

    /**
    * Filter by Product Tag
    *
    * @param array $filterArray
    */
    private function filterTag($filterArray)
    {
        $this->queryBuilder
        ->whereHas('tag',function($query) use ($filterArray){
            return $query->where('name','=',$filterArray['value']);
        }); 
    }

    /*
     * Filter Functions: END
     */


    /*
    * Order By Functions: START
    */

    /**
    * Order By Name
    * @param array $orderByArray
    */
    private function orderByName($orderByArray)
    {
        $this->queryBuilder
        ->orderBy('name', $orderByArray['value']);
    }

    /*
    * Order By Functions: END
    */    
}
```

**How to Use:**

```
//In my controller function

public function getListOfProducts(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    //Init Product Query
    $productQuery = \App\Models\Product()::newQuery();

    //Apply all filters and order bys
    $productFilter = app('ProductFilter',[$request,$productQuery])->applyFilters()->applyOrderBys();

    //Fetch Product Result
    $productResult = $productQuery->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very informative

Comment: Glad to help. A `filterItem` class can be used in placed of arrays to declare your filter options. It will become handy in situations where you have to do validation of your filter values, or have complex rules of when the filter is active & valid.