# Shortening if else for multiple $_GET variables

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel for an API and trying to fetch multiple _GET variables a user would type.

The code looks like this when all filters are used:

```
 public function MUIntervalAPICall(Request $dte)
    {
      $date = $dte->dte;
      $element_language = $dte->language;
      $element_customer = $dte->customer;
      $element_contract = $dte->contract;
      $element_subcontract = $dte->subcontract;
      $element = $dte->element;

      //all filters

      if(isset($_GET['customer']) && isset($_GET['language']) && isset($_GET['contract']) && isset($_GET['subcontract']) && isset($_GET['element']))
      {
        $where = ['dte' => $date, 'element_language' => $element_language, 'element_customer' => $element_customer, 'element_contract' => $element_contract, 'element_subcontract' => $element_subcontract, 'element' => $element];
      }

      $mu_interval = MUInterval::select('element_customer', 'element_contract', 'element_subcontract', 'element_language', 'element_site', 'element', 'src_id', 'src_type_id', 'dte', 'intvl', 'val_src_id', 'exception_name', 'duration_seconds', 'duration_fte')
          ->where($where) 
          ->get()->toArray();
      function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
          foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
              if( is_array($value) ) {
                  $key = 'Exception';
                  $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
                  array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
              } else {
                  $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
              }
           }
      }
      $xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><muExceptions></muExceptions>');
      array_to_xml($mu_interval,$xml_data);
      $result = $xml_data->asXML();
      return Response::make($result, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
```

Now a user would want to filter it out only with few variables in place. e.g. date and customer, or language and contract only.
I'm currently writing a long block of if-else statements to produce results (really long, to include all possibilities for six $_GET variables):

```
elseif(isset($_GET['subcontract']) && isset($_GET['element']))
      {
        $where = ['dte' => $date, 'element' => $element, 'element_subcontract' => $element_subcontract];
      }
```

Is there a shorter method for such a long if-else statements?

Comment: Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431412/creating-a-filterable-list-using-laravel-and-eloquent-queries/35433377#35433377 It might help to abstract the logic of your filtering into a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should learn about how Laravel validation and form request validation work:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation

It's much shorter and more convenient way to do validation.

Answer (score 0):

Write your conditions as below:-

```
if(isset($_GET['subcontract'],$_GET['element']) && !isset($_GET['customer'], $_GET['language'], $_GET['contract'])){
   $where = ['dte' => $date, 'element' => $element, 'element_subcontract' => $element_subcontract];
}

elseif(isset($_GET['customer'], $_GET['language'], $_GET['contract'], $_GET['subcontract'],$_GET['element'])){
   $where = ['dte' => $date, 'element_language' => $element_language, 'element_customer' => $element_customer, 'element_contract' => $element_contract, 'element_subcontract' => $element_subcontract, 'element' => $element];
}
```

**Suggestion**:- You should use Laravel's Validator Class for validations.

Refer below links.

http://www.sitepoint.com/data-validation-laravel-right-way/

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation

Answer (score 0):

1. `isset` accepts multiple arguments at once:

   ```
   if (isset($_GET['customer'], $_GET['language'], $_GET['contract'], ...))
   ```
2. You can use array intersections/diffs:

   ```
   if (!array_key_diff(array_flip(['customer', 'language', ...]), $_GET))
   ```

   If [`array_key_diff`](http://php.net/array_key_diff) returns an empty array, all those keys exist in the `$_GET` array.